# Splittig MapReduce output into multiple output files

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce, hdfs

Is it possible to split the output of a mapreduce job into multiple files instead of a single 'part-r-00000' file?

I've came across the MultipleOutputFormat class, but from what I've read it seems that it only breaks the output into files based on the key. [MultipleOutputFormat](https://sites.google.com/site/hadoopandhive/home/how-to-write-output-to-multiple-named-files-in-hadoop-using-multipletextoutputformat)

What I am looking for is, to take the WordCount job as an example, to just divide the output into more than 1 file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Forgive me, but typically you get as many part-r-nnnnn files as you have reducer tasks.  If the word count example has only one reducer configured, all you have to do is configure more than one (mapred.reduce.tasks or the Hadoop 2 equivalent).

Comment: Thank you. I realise I've always left the reducer tasks as default without setting the value, so it has always been 1.

Answer (score 3):

I have a similar problem regarding Wordcount. In my case I need to write words starts with each letter into separate files.Here I used `MultipleOutputs`.

```
public class NameCountReducer extends Reducer<Text, NameCountTuple, Text, NameCountTuple> {
private NameCountTuple result = null;
private MultipleOutputs<Text,NameCountTuple> out;

 public void setup(Context context) {
   out = new MultipleOutputs<Text,NameCountTuple>(context);   
 }
public void reduce(Text key, Iterable<NameCountTuple> values, Context context)
        throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    int count = 0;
    for (HITuple val : values) {

        count += val.getCount();
    }
    result.setCount(count);
    out.write(key, result,"outputpath/"+key.getText().charAt(0));
}
public void cleanup(Context context) throws IOException,InterruptedException {
    out.close();        
 }
```

}

Here it gives output in the following paths as

```
outputpath/a
          /b
          /c
 .......
```

For this you should use `LazyOutputFormat.setOutputFormatClass()` instead of `FileOutputFormat`. Also need to add job configuration as `job.setOutputFormatClass(NullOutputFormat.class)`

Comment: hi @TomSebastian. Thank you for the help. Actually my MapReduce job is a simple search job, and so it only runs the map tasks without the reduce tasks, and I just wanted it to output all the search results to multiple output files. Nonetheless thank you for the info. Will probably provide use as i continue building the program

Answer (score -1):

Thank you all for the above suggestions.

The MapReduce Job I have is actually just a simple search job, with the map tasks extracting the input lines that matches a certain condition. And then to simply output that result without going thru any reduce tasks.

Initially i did not set the reduce tasks number and from the output logs i could see that it defaults as 1. I tried to set to a higher number but somehow it does produce multiple output files (part-000xx) but only one of the output files will carry all the results while the rest are just empty files.

Then when I set this below, it worked. With each reduce tasks output being the final output file. I'm not really sure if this is the correct way to do it but I'll take it for now as a workaround

> conf.set("mapred.reduce.tasks", "0")